# does sqlite3 engine need to be installed separately from rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Does **gem install sqlite3** takes care of installing both the underlying engine as well as the ruby module (gem)?

Do I need to install sqlite3 from the sqlite3 website first, and then install the sqlite3 gem with the gem command?

Comment: sqlite needs to be installed separately yes. But please do yourself a favor and use a real db, postgres or mysql, it will save you mane headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [docs](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby):

> This module allows Ruby programs to interface with the SQLite3 database engine (www.sqlite.org). You must have the SQLite engine installed in order to build this module.

`gem install sqlite3` or a running bundler with Gemfile including `gem 'sqlite3'` will only install the database driver – the interface you need to connect a Ruby application with an SQLite database.

The same is true for other well-known database drivers – like `mysql2` or `pg`. The database engine itself must be installed separately and it usually has be installed before installing the gem.

Comment: Is it included with msys2 though? I installed that, and I saw libsqlite3 was installed along with it.

Comment: I am not familiar with msys2 and do not know what packages are installed with msys2 per default. But there is a [sqlite package](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/sqlite) for msys2, therefore it seems possible.